# Numerical Method for Process on Unit Sphere

Tags: numerical-methods, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, approximation, spherical-coordinates

I have a stochastic process with additive noise on the unit sphere, parametrized by angles (i.e. hyper-spherical coordinates with $r=1$):
$$ \theta_t = \psi(Z_t)dt + \sigma(Z_t,\theta_t)dW_t \tag{1} $$
where  $Z_t$ is a different process and $\theta_t\in\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. 
We can convert to Cartesian coordinates via $ C_t = C(\theta_t) $, where $\mathbb{R}^n$.
The nice fact is that using $\theta_t$ stays on the unit sphere, but in this case $\sigma$ has a singularity in spherical coordinates.

So I was wondering what happens if I do the following, as a numerical discretization (like a corrected Euler-Maruyama):
$$
\tilde{C}_{t+1} = C_t + \eta(Z_t) \Delta t + \tilde{\sigma}(Z_t,C_t)\Delta W_t
$$
$$ C_{t+1} = \frac{\tilde{C}_{t+1}}{||\tilde{C}_{t+1}||_2} $$
where $\tilde{\sigma}(Z_t,C_t)$ and $\eta(Z_t)$ are the Cartesian forms of $\sigma$ and $\psi$, and $\tilde{C}$ is the "initial" unnormalized version of $C_t$.

Questions: **how much error will this incur as opposed to discretizing eq (1) directly? Will this converge to the same process for small enough $\Delta t$?**